# How to show App intro slider once built on expo using typescript using asyncStorage

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I'm using react-native-app-intro-slider to show an onboarding for my app built on expo using typescript. I want the slider to only show for the first time during launch but seem to be having trouble with it.

I'm quite new to typescript but I've looked around and all of the solutions seem to be for react native using asyncStorage.

Not sure if I'm doing it right here.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'

const data = [{...}, {...}, {...}]

AsyncStorage.setItem('showIntro', 'true')

function App() {
  { (AsyncStorage.getItem('showIntro') === 'true') ? (
      <AppIntroSlider
        renderItem={renderItem}
        data={data}
        onDone={onDone}/>
      ) : (
        <ShowApp />
      )
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `onDone` will be called once your slider finishes. you can pass your function to the `onDone` handler and set the `screen` to false.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'

const data = [{...}, {...}, {...}]

const getScreen = async () => {
  return await AsyncStorage.getItem('showIntro'); 
}

function App() {
  const [showIntro, updateShowIntro] = React.useState(getScreen());

  const onDone = () => {
     AsyncStorage.setItem('showIntro', false).then(()=>{});
     updateShowIntro(false);
  }

  return (
  { showIntro ? (
      <AppIntroSlider
        renderItem={renderItem}
        data={data}
        onDone={onDone}/>
      ) : (
        <ShowApp />
      )
    }
  );
 }
```

Comment: I have a onDone already, just not shown :)
But AsyncStorage.getItem('showIntro') is returning a promise so 'true' will never match

Below is my onDone

  const onDone = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('showIntro', 'false')
  }

Comment: Think it's getting there, but still doesn't work :( I've change the false in AsyncStorage.setItem('showIntro', false) in onDone to a string because AsyncStorage can only store strings (correct me if I'm wrong)

When restarting the app, the intro slider still appears

Comment: after updating it to string did you also update `showIntro === 'true'` in return method.

Comment: Yeah I did, doesn't show. When I console log showIntro, it returns a promise

Comment: I don't have RN set up so I cannot test but the steps should be similar. Try console log inside `getScreen` and see what its returning.

Comment: It initially shows null if it's the first time time being opened.

I tried to change the condition of `showIntro` to check for null, but for some reason it always returns a promise object even if `showIntro` is null